# admin_post_nopriv_{$action} is secure?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks

I want to send some data to my plugin from another program with admin-post.php. But I am dubious to use admin_post_nopriv_{$action} because it Fires on a non-authenticated admin post request for the given action.

admin_post_nopriv_{$action} is secure to use?

Comment: Posting this as comment, as I don't know an answer to your question. But have you considered exposing a REST endpoint from your plugin that you use from the external application? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: How does your other program authenticate itself to WordPress? You'll have to use nopriv (or some other mechanism) unless it logs itself in. But I agree a REST endpoint is probably the way to go, e.g. using a JWT or the new application password mechanism for authentication.

Comment: Any hook that allows non authenticated users to interact should be treated differently, with less trust - but that does not make them insecure, only how you handle the code within them.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `admin-post.php`, especially if you're making requests from another program. Use the REST API instead

Comment: Yes, we thought to use a REST endpoint above link (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) . Right now, we don't have any authenticate system in another program for WordPress. Thanks for your answers. I guess, we choose the REST endpoint to request data.